# Включение CodeLens в Visual Studio 2017 Community?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Есть просто невероятно удобная штука в Visual Studio - CodeLens, которая нереально удобная в использовании. Она была включена по дэфолту в 2013 Ultimate и 2015 Pro версиях VS.

Как использовать в VS 2017 Community?

При чем мне удавалось врубить CodeLens фичу в 2015 версии без установки PRO -- установкой SSDT.

Может быть это возможно и в 2017 каким-то макаром?
Или есть ли аналогичный по функционалу аддон к этой VS?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добрый день, @Andrew. Мне казалось, что в ReSharper 2018.2 они должны были добавить эту функцию. К сожалению у меня нет возможности проверить это.

Comment: А решарпер 2018 поддерживает комьюнити редакцию? Более ранние поддерживали только про и выше, если память не изменяет. А они и так имеют CodeLens сами по себе

Comment: вот тут пишут, что да [resharper-support](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241605-Does-ReSharper-work-with-Visual-Studio-Express-or-Community-Edition-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codelens недоступен в Community версии 2017. Только начиная с редакции Pro.
Доступные возможности между редакциями можно посмотреть здесь:
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/vs/compare/

Comment: он был официанльно недоступен и в Community версии 2015... что не мешало мне им пользоватся и в таком случае. Да и из этого не следует что нету никаких плагинов его заменяющих... Меня не причины интересуют(их я знаю и так), а способ выйти из положения... Окроме как качать пиратку Pro.