# Можно-ли сделать объявления о ссылках в vs code такими как в vs studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

[image: Вот как выглядит это в VS code]

[image: Хотелось что бы выглядело вот так как в Visual Studio]

вычитал что был раньше C#StyleFix но его удалили из marketplace, есть ли такая извращённая возможность ?

Answer (score 0):

Эта штука называется Code Lens. И она есть только в платной версии вижуал студио.

Если [эта ссылка](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/02/12/code-lens-roundup) не поможет - ищи другие по запросу `"vs code" "codeLens"`

Comment: У меня на Community спокойно работает, но отключаю ее.

Comment: Хм... может и бесплатной сделали в последней версии вижуалки. В предпоследней точно не было - и я потратил очень много времени что бы выяснить почему) Еще от меня был вот этот вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/918057/%d0%92%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-codelens-%d0%b2-visual-studio-2017-community . В 2019 тоже не было в комьюнити версии.

Comment: только что включил CodeLenses. VS Community последняя версия - 16.11.2. Но давно при установке VS, действительно, не было CodeLenses. Это сейчас при каждой установке приходится мне отключать ее) пруф: https://i.ibb.co/grFQS40/image.png

Comment: Вот и прекрасно) Буду знать) Жаль только вижуалкой уже не пользуюсь)